# Why is a function from a Julia submodule being shadowed?

Tags: module, namespaces, julia, shadowing

Consider the following code:

```
module Foo
export g, h

  module Bar
  export f

  f(::Int) = 2

  end

using .Bar

f(::String) = "abc"

g() = f("a")
h() = f(12)

end
```

When I run this, if I try calling `g()` I get `"abc"` as expected.  If I call `h()` I get an error message.  Somehow, the definition of `f(::Int)` is being shadowed.  Is that supposed to happen?  How to fix this?

If I omit the definition of `f(::String)` then `h()` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behaviour. In order to extend method it should be imported (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#using-and-import-with-specific-identifiers,-and-adding-methods)

So, correct example should look like this:

```
module Foo
export g, h

  module Bar
  export f

  f(::Int) = 2

  end

using .Bar
import .Bar: f

f(::String) = "abc"

g() = f("a")
h() = f(12)

end
```

I've added `import .Bar: f` because `Bar` can export other names, which you do not want to extend. So it is fine to mix these two together. With this addition, everything is working as intended

```
julia> using .Foo

julia> g()
"abc"

julia> h()
2
```